# RedShift - case statement failing CASE/WHEN must be type boolean, not type character varying;

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, case

trying to run below query but getting error. all fields in when are date

```
select  
     dt.*,
     case when dt.search_mst_date then 'Daily'
          when dt.search_mst_week then 'Weekly'
          when dt.search_mst_month then 'Monthly'
          when dt.search_mst_quarter then 'Quarterly'
          when dt.search_mst_year then 'Yearly'
       end as aggregation_type
    from cte_dt dt
  group by dt.*
```

Amazon Invalid operation: argument of CASE/WHEN must be type boolean, not type character varying;

Comment: What type is "dt.search_mst_date"? If numeric, then you have to use `when dt.search_mst_date = 1` or some similar suitable condition - same for other cases.

Answer (score 0):

your field after when statement must be a boolean datatype not date or any other datatype.
for example:

```
case when TRUE then 'desired output' ... end as alias
```

instead of `TRUE`, you need to either use a comparison of some sort or a column that is already in boolean type.

Comment: but want to use case statement on date field then what to do?

Comment: can you share a screenshot of your data and explain what you want to achieve first?